# How to get images from web Multiple URL (website url.html)

Tags: excel, vba, windows

How to get **images** from web **Multiple URL** (website url.html)

Answer (score 0):

So I would do it using the 'Microsoft HTML Object Library' and 'Microsoft Internet Controls' libraries- see webscraping examples, give it a shot, then post your code and let us know how it went.

Regards,
TheSilkCode